# How to get \shortintertext and \intertext to color their inline math contents in beamer?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, mathtools

I would like the intertext of math to be colored even inside `\shortintertext` and `\intertext`. Using

`\newcommand{\colorInlinedMath}{\everymath{\color{SpringGreen3}}\sisetup{color=SpringGreen3}}`

I switch the colors, but I must use it for every `\shortintertext` and `\intertext`

[image]

How do I get the result of the third entry without having to change the color manually for every `\shortintertext` and `\intertext`?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes, subdued, italic, LGRgreek, symbolre]{mathastext}

\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=SpringGreen3}
\newcommand{\colorInlinedMath}{\everymath{\color{SpringGreen3}}\sisetup{color=SpringGreen3}}

\begin{document}
        
\begin{frame}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        
        \item  $I_{f} = i_{L}(\infty) = \SI{0}{\ampere}$ (\alert{why?}). $\omega_{d}$ is given by
            
            \begin{alignat*}{2}
            \shortintertext{$I_{f} = i_{L}(\infty) = \SI{0}{\ampere}$ (\alert{why?}). $\omega_{d}$ is given by}
                \omega_{d} &= \sqrt{\omega_{0}^{2} - \alpha^{2}}
            \\
            \shortintertext{\colorInlinedMath $I_{f} = i_{L}(\infty) = \SI{0}{\ampere}$ (\alert{why?}). $\omega_{d}$ is given by}
                \omega_{d} &= \sqrt{\omega_{0}^{2} - \alpha^{2}}
            \end{alignat*}
        
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Couldn’t you just patch `\shortintertext` and `\intertext`?

Comment: Something like `\let\originalintertext\intertext \renewcommand\intertext[1]{\originalintertext{<color setup>#1}}`.

Comment: beamer explicitly disables the math coloring in the \noalign of intertext, and changing that will probably affect other places where you don't want the color. Consider a special command or patch like suggested by @RuixiZhang.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with the `\pretocmd` command  from `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}, t, handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes, subdued, italic, LGRgreek, symbolre]{mathastext}

\setbeamercolor{math text inlined}{fg=SpringGreen3}
\newcommand{\colorInlinedMath}{\everymath{\color{SpringGreen3}}\sisetup{color=SpringGreen3}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\intertext@}{\colorInlinedMath}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{itemize}

        \item $I_{f} = i_{L}(\infty) = \SI{0}{\ampere}$ (\alert{why?}). $\omega_{d}$ is given by

            \begin{alignat*}{2}
            \shortintertext{$I_{f} = i_{L}(\infty) = \SI{0}{\ampere}$ (\alert{why?}). $\omega_{d}$ is given by}
                \omega_{d} &= \sqrt{\omega_{0}^{2} - \alpha^{2}}
            \\
            \shortintertext{\colorInlinedMath $I_{f} = i_{L}(\infty) = \SI{0}{\ampere}$ (\alert{why?}). $\omega_{d}$ is given by}
                \omega_{d} &= \sqrt{\omega_{0}^{2} - \alpha^{2}}
            \end{alignat*}

    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this changes all of the following display math color

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh: It seems I misunderstood the details of your requirements. I'll see whether it can be fixed.